# Defining the Choquet Integral in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

I would like to define and use the [Choquet integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_integral) in Mathematica.

I think the first step should be to define a representation of a non-additive (normalized) measure $\nu:\Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$. Thus, I tried to define some sort of distribution function $F_\nu(x)$ that represents the measure of the sets $(- \infty, x]$. A so-called distorted measure $\nu = h \circ P$, where $h:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is an increasing function and $P$ a probability measure would do the job.

For instance, letting $h:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be $h(x)=x^2$ and using the continuous uniform distribution for the sake of simplicity:

```
h[x_] = x^2
F[x_] = CDF[\[ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", \[CDF[UniformDistribution[], t]]}, {t, -∞, ∞}]], x]
```

But here I got stuck since I do not know how I need to tell Matheatica to evaluate something like $\int{\nu(\{\omega \in \Omega| f(\omega) \geq x\}) dx}$.

Any ideas to get this running (maybe there is a much more elegant solution)?

Comment: `F[x_] = CDF[\[ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", \[CDF[UniformDistribution[], t]]}, {t, -∞, ∞}]], x]` is an ill-fromed expression and will not evaluate. What is the real definition of `F` in your Mathematica notebook?

Comment: @m_goldberg .Thanks for the hint. First I define the function $h$ by h[x_]=x^2. Then I define the prob distribution by setting \[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 
   h[CDF[UniformDistribution[], t]]}, {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]. Finally I put F[x_] = CDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x] .

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:

```
ChoquetIntegral[h_, dist_] := NIntegrate[InverseCDF[dist, x] h'[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

For your example:

```
ChoquetIntegral[#^2&, UniformDistribution[]]
```

> 0.666667

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late response and thanks a lot for your support. Could you shortly outline how you came to this proposal? If I calculate the Choquet integral of $f(x)=x$ with respect to the measure $\nu = h \circ P$ (as defined above) then I come to the same result.

Comment: I just used the alternate representation from your Wikipedia reference